# How can I rename fields with the builtin json tracing subscriber?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

The `tracing` json subscriber gives the following stdout out of the box:

```rust
fn main() {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .json()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::DEBUG)
        .flatten_event(true)
        .init();

    tracing::debug!("This is a debug message");
}
```

```bash
{"timestamp":"2023-07-14T20:47:29.302872Z","level":"DEBUG","message":"This is a debug message","target":"publisher"}
```

How can I rename the field "level" to "severity"?

I tried to use the `fmt::format::debug_fn` but it doesn't seem to be compatible.

Comment: Last time I checked the code the JSON field names were not configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The name `"level"` is hardcoded into `tracing-subscriber`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/0.3.17/src/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/json.rs.html#247-249), so I don't think you can change it without writing your own implementation of [`FormatEvent`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/trait.FormatEvent.html).